# On-premises Central Device Management tool

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch

This might be a duplicate, but after a days of research I haven't found an answer to this. I'm looking for a device manager tool to which I can register tens/hundreds of Raspberry Pis located inside of local company network. Some of the pies are connected to the main firewall in the headquarters, some are in branch offices accessed via IPSec VPN tunnel. The main condition is that this tool should be installed on the local on-premises PC/server - something like [HP Device Manager](https://www.google.nl/search?q=hp%20device%20manager&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib7p_p05PaAhXLL1AKHX27CmYQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=oHFkdVIbab3-oM:) for HP Thin Clients (amazing tool).

I found a very nice tool [remot3.it](https://www.remot3.it/web/remot3-it-connect-for-raspberry-pi.html), it lets me register the pie, see it in the dashboard, access it via VNC, SSH, but mainly I can send any shell script to it. A pity is that it requires to open UDP ports and essentially stores all information on the 3rd party servers, we need to have everything locally. Also found [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) and [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), but haven't tested these yet and don't know if they can be installed locally on the server.

Does anybody know about such a piece of software which can be installed on the local server and manage connected pies? Main use of it would be to send shell scripts to the pies (reboot, managing accounts, update & upgrade, etc.).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome! I would ask this at https://serverfault.com/